# Import images from the assets folder and set them as button thumbnails

Tags: python, filmic-blender

I need to import images from the assets folder and then set these images as button thumbnails for the first part I did it but no thumbnail was previewed only small images, not my photos this is my code

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel, AddonPreferences
from bpy.props import EnumProperty, StringProperty
import os

# Preferences
class MyAddonPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__

    category_options = [
        ("CLASSIC", "Classic", "Classic category"),
        ("MODERN", "Modern", "Modern category"),
    ]

    category: EnumProperty(
        name="Category",
        items=category_options,
        default="CLASSIC",
    )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "category")

# Operator to display the selected image
class MY_OT_DisplayImage(Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.display_image"
    bl_label = "Display Image"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    file_name: StringProperty()
    category_path: StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        image_path = os.path.join(self.category_path, self.file_name)

        # Dummy operation for demonstration purposes
        print("Selected Image Path:", image_path)

        return {'FINISHED'}

# Panel for category selection and image preview buttons
class MY_PT_CategoryPreview(Panel):
    bl_idname = "PT_CategoryPreview"
    bl_label = "Frameify"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Frameify'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        preferences = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
        category_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'assets', preferences.category + '_Preview')

        # Display category selection at the top
        layout.prop(preferences, "category", text="")

        # Display image preview buttons with thumbnails
        for file_name in os.listdir(category_path):
            if file_name.lower().endswith(".png"):
                image_path = os.path.join(category_path, file_name)
                thumb_icon = bpy.data.images.get(file_name)

                if thumb_icon:
                    icon_value = layout.icon(thumb_icon)
                else:
                    icon_value = 'IMAGE_DATA'

                layout.operator("my.display_image", text="", icon="IMAGE_DATA").file_name = file_name



# Collections and Registration
classes = [
    MyAddonPreferences,
    MY_OT_DisplayImage,
    MY_PT_CategoryPreview,
]

def register():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager

    bpy.utils.register_class(MyAddonPreferences)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OT_DisplayImage)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_PT_CategoryPreview)

    WindowManager.my_previews_dir = StringProperty(
        name="Folder Path",
        subtype='DIR_PATH',
        default="",
    )

def unregister():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyAddonPreferences)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OT_DisplayImage)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_PT_CategoryPreview)

    del WindowManager.my_previews_dir

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```